# App can't see wide angle camera in xiaomi redmi note 9

Tags: applications, camera, xiaomi, redmi

I have `Xiaomi Redmi Note 9`. With standard `Camera` app I can make video using wide angle camera (x0.6). But using `DJI Mimo`, `A Better Camera` or `Filmic pro` I can use only my standard camera (x1.0). Can I fix it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know such "special cameras" are often not accessible via Android's standard camera API, hence each app needs to be adapted for your device to be able to use e.g. the wide angle camera. This require a lot of effort so not every camera app developer does this.

Therefore the answer is: You can't fix this on your own, only the developer of the camera app can adapt the app to make it work.