# Is there a way to access the wide-angle camera in xiaomi redmi 9 from the computer?

Tags: camera, xiaomi, python

I'm currently trying to access the wide angle camera that xiaomi redmi 9 has. My end-goal is to be able to stream frames from the camera in a python script (using [openCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#capture-video-from-camera)). But knowing how to access this camera from the computer will be enough.

So far, I've tried to do this by using [Droidcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dev47apps.droidcam&hl=es&gl=US), [iVcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.e2esoft.ivcam&hl=es&gl=US) and [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=es&gl=US). They work great with the main camera, but I'm unable to use the wide-angle one.

I've found a similar question [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231153/app-cant-see-wide-angle-camera-in-xiaomi-redmi-note-9), but I believe that my question may be different as it's more specific.

*PS: I'm completely new here so I'm not sure if this is the correct stack exchange to ask this. I'm sorry if it's not.*

Comment: If something does not work now may just mean that no one has yet tried to change the situation. If I would be you I would try to find a non-Xiaomi camera app that can access the wide-angle camera. Best would be an open source app. Check also xda-developers forum for that topic. Once you found a working app ask the developers of the mentioned IP cam apps If they can add access to that can and link to the working cam app. If the way how to access that can is clear it should be not a big problem to add it to other apps (for an app developer).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Robert